# How to get a web service response using ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2 to call web services in my android app. It worked on quite a few occasions but somehow I'm not able to get past this one. I call a web service from my activity using another class mentioned below:

```
public class ServiceCall {
    public static String loginID; 
public static String password; 
public static String authStatus;
public static String firstName;
public static String lastName;

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.tempuri.us/";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.tempuri.us/";
private static final String URL = "http://test.tempuriprojects.com/WebServices/GetWorkData.asmx";

private boolean isResultVector = true;

protected Object call(String soapAction, SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope){
    Object result = null;


    final HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    transportSE.debug = false;


    //call and Parse Result.        
    try{
        transportSE.call(soapAction, envelope);


        if (!isResultVector){
            result = envelope.getResponse();
            Log.e("RESULT: ", result.toString());
        } else {
            result = envelope.bodyIn;
            Log.e("RESULT1: ", envelope.bodyIn.toString());
        } 
    } catch (final IOException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final Exception e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}


    public ArrayList<DashboardEntry> getDashboardEntries(DashboardEntryCriteria bean){
    ArrayList<DashboardEntry> dashboardEntryList = new ArrayList<DashboardEntry>();
    try{
        String methodName = "GetDashboardEntries";

        // Create the outgoing message
        final SoapObject requestObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);

        bean.setLoginID("100");
        bean.setPassword("12345");

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfo.setName("dashboardentries");
        propertyInfo.setType(bean.getClass());
        propertyInfo.setValue(bean);
        requestObject.addProperty(propertyInfo);

        //create soap envelop : soap version 1.1 
        final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.xsd = "http://tempuri.org/GetDashboardEntries.xsd";
        envelope.addMapping(null, "dashboardentries", new DashboardEntryCriteria().getClass());
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;

        // add the outgoing object as the request
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestObject);

        // call and Parse Result.
        final Object response = this.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodName, envelope);

        SoapObject soapObj = (SoapObject)response;

        int j = 0;
        for(int i=0;  i < length; i++)
        {

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapObj.getProperty(i);

            if(soapObj != null ){

            if(result.hasProperty("AuthStatus") && String.valueOf(result.getProperty("AuthStatus").toString()).equals("Y")){

                loginID = result.getProperty("LoginID").toString(); 
                System.out.println(loginID);
                password = result.getProperty("Password").toString(); 
                System.out.println(password);
                authStatus = result.getProperty("AuthStatus").toString();
                System.out.println(authStatus);

                // Irrelevant code
            }   

            }

        }
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Exception: ", e.toString());
    }
    return dashboardEntryList ;
}
```

This is the DashboardEntryCriteria bean:

```
public class DashboardEntryCriteria implements KvmSerializable{

private String LoginID;
private String Password;



/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}


/**
 * @return the loginID
 */
public String getLoginID() {
    return LoginID;
}

/**
 * @param loginID the loginID to set
 */
public void setLoginID(String loginID) {
    LoginID = loginID;
}

}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

    switch(arg0){
    case 0 : return LoginID;
    case 1 : return Password;

    }
    return null;

}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {

    switch(arg0){
    case 0 : 
        arg2.name = "LoginID";
        arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        arg2.namespace = "http://tempuri.org/RxGetWorkEntries.xsd";
        break;
    case 1 : 
        arg2.name = "Password";
        arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        arg2.namespace = "http://tempuri.org/RxGetWorkEntries.xsd";
        break;

    }

}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {

    switch(arg0){
    case 0 : 
        LoginID = arg1.toString();
        break;
    case 1 : 
        Password = arg1.toString();
        break;

    }

}
```

}
 I'm positive that the error is in the class ServiceCall somewhere in the method `getDashboardEntries()`. I noticed that when the method `call` is called it gives the empty response (or "result" object). I did try calling the web service using soapUI with the same parameters, it works just fine. Just to let you know that there isn't anything wrong with the web service. So any idea what else could be wrong or missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SOAP_ACTION should be something like this.

```
AppConsts.NAMESPACE =  "http://www.tempuri.us/"
```

usecaseString = THIS SHOULD BE YOUR METHOD NAME OF SERVICE.
String soapAction = AppConsts.NAMESPACE + usecaseString;

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396805/create-soap-request-using-ksoap-androidurgent/9413683#9413683) answer of this question to get detailed explanation.

Comment: And your URL should be something like this.
NAMESPACE+/PROJECTNAME/SERVICE_NAME.asmx

Comment: If your webservice is on localhost then you must have to provide your IP. then Your URL will be URL = "http://192.168.2.140/WebServices/GetWorkData.asmx";

Comment: My NAMESPACE and soapAction are exactly like that. I've initialized soap action as my namespace but I pass "soapAction + methodName" because I have multiple methods in my code. Also my web service is not on the localhost. And as I mentioned in the question I've gone though several tutorials and some of the methods work just fine. There must be something in particular about this code snippet that's wrong and/or missing. I'd really appreciate if you could point that out for me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give me service URL and method you calling so i can see it in detail. Thanks

Comment: Actually I've tried requesting object using soapUI and I do get a proper response.  That's why I know the problem is in the code. My guess is the parameters I'm trying to pass to the request object aren't set properly. I think the problem is in the bean. Because I'm getting a response but not the desired one which requires proper parameters to be set. Could you tell if the request object receives proper values in the above code?

Comment: use request dump to see if your request is being sent in proper way. here is the code to see request.
`AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport (URL); androidHttpTransport.debug = true; androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_UPDATE_SETTINGS, envelope); Log.d("MyAPP", "----------------- " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump );`

Comment: Thank a lot. I somehow am not able to use AndroidHttpTransport, I guess my jar doesn't have that. However, HttpTransportSE has worked just fine for me before.

Comment: Nice you got it working :). Vote up on other answers will be much appreciated thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
  SoapPrimitive resultSoapPrimitive;
        resultSoapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        if (resultSoapPrimitive != null) {
            result = resultSoapPrimitive.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you [this](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) tutorial. After going through this you will be able to understand complete concept.